# Android - Measure Distance to target object

Tags: android, camera, zooming, distance

Can someone help, I need to do this kind of application, but simpler. So you take a picture and calculate the distance ...

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.potatotree.manualdistance

Is there a good tutorial that recommends???
thank you.

Comment: Please, share your attempts? Have You tried to implement it?

Answer (score 2):

There is a way of doing it simple, but I think it would be *very* inaccurate. Take a look at this triangle:
[image: triangle]

Now, imagine there is a person standing along `a`.

1. If this person is pointing his camera at `A`, then using [`SensorManager.getOrientation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation%28float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D%29), you could obtain `α` angle.
2. If you asked the user about his height, you could also get `a`.
3. In this case, `tan(α)=a/b`. So the distance equals `b=`**`a/tan(α)`**

It seems easy but all the errors that sum up in the process make the result almost completely unusable. And moreover it would "work" only on flat ground. When it's steep, you'd have to know the vertical difference between the person and the point measured and make even more calculations.

So, yeah, you *can* make it simple, but do you really want to?

Answer (score 1):

There's not really a physical way to get distance from a single point image.  You need some sort of parallax in order to determine how far away it is.

This is why you lose depth perception when you cover one eye - you lose the parallax (distance between two reference points) when you do this.

You need to know at least one side in order to estimate the length of a triangle.

Laser rangefinders get around this by measuring the return time of a laser pulse, not by scanning an image.